# Dropwizard: How to fix 414 Request-URI Too Long

Tags: jetty, dropwizard

Request (GET) or (POST):

http://localhost:8080/images?name=iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA%20AAAFC......

Response:

Status Code: 414 Request-URI Too Long
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0

How to increase the request size?

Comment: As you mention GET or POST, why not switch to a POST ? The error is about sending lots of data in URL. Even if you can increase it in your server, you could still get into trouble with proxy, for example. Post seems a much more adequate type of request for your case.

Comment: proper answer is to **NOT** change the limit. You shouldn't be sending overly-long data as a query parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a Request URI that is over 8kb in size!  Eeesh!

Request-URI limits exist because of various vulnerabilities and bugs found in browsers, proxies, and networking hardware.

While it is possible to increase the Request URI limit checks in Jetty, the values chosen for Jetty represent the current safe maximums in use by various http clients and intermediaries on the public internet.

**WARNING: YOU DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS**

This is inappropriate for:

- A WebServer accessible from the Internet.
- A WebServer accessed by browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari, MSIE, or Opera.
- A WebServer accessed by a mobile device like Android, iOS, or Microsoft mobile.
- A WebServer that has a proxy in front of it.
- A client that uses a proxy to access the WebServer.

This is only useful for transactions limited between custom HTTP clients directly talking to  a Jetty server.

**Instructions for Jetty 9.2.6.v20141205**

If you don't have a Jetty Base `${jetty.base}` directory yet, create one, and initialize it.

```
[user]$ mkdir mybase
[user]$ cd mybase
[mybase]$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-distribution-9.2.6.v20141205/start.jar \
            --add-to-start=http,deploy,webapp
```

Edit the `${jetty.base}/start.ini`

And change (or add) the following property with your desired upper limit.

```
jetty.request.header.size=8192
```

And no, there is no way to disable this limit check.

For each increase you open yourself up to greater and greater issues.

Starting with some browsers (and eventually all browsers) not being send the request, let alone jetty receiving it.

Meanwhile the ability of many proxy servers to handle your request starts to fail, resulting in terminated and failed connections or requests.  Sometimes even truncated requests to Jetty.

Also each increase exposes you to various vulnerabilities surrounding unchecked limits in headers, resulting in the ability of various groups in executing CPU and Memory based DOS attacks that require very little network traffic to perform.

**The Correct Way to Fix This:**

You really should switch to POST (or PUT) based request data, and not be sending that amount of data in the request headers of the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 2):

A possibly easier way is to set the requestHeaderSize in your yaml config file.  Here is an extract from ours:

```
    server:
      applicationConnectors:
      - type: http
        maxRequestHeaderSize: 100KiB
```

Other possible settings are shown [here](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.0/docs/manual/configuration.html#http)