# Can I configure jetty header buffer or request buffer to handle requests large in size?

Tags: jetty, httprequest

Right now, if a request length is large, I get either "URI is too large >8192" or "Header is too large >8192"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropwizard: How to fix 414 Request-URI Too Long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950281/dropwizard-how-to-fix-414-request-uri-too-long)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549163/set-maximum-url-length-in-jetty

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt both these are about URI size, but not about header size

Comment: There's no difference in configuration, same configuration impacts both errors you reported.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt You made my day! I didn't bother to check the queries which resulted in "URI is too large" after solving "Header is too large" with that config entry. And if I hadn't read your comment, I probably would have wondered why they disappeared "magically". :-)