# How can I send a String list as param with a lot of items in a get mapping request in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, controller, http-get

I have a Spring boot controller with a get request method to be used as Rest API, this one.

The third param, **ids**, is a String list. Usually it is not a problem, but sometimes this list needs to have more than a six hundreds of items, and it launch an error because length limit on the URI.

```
@GetMapping("/mhcil/details")
public ResponseEntity findDetails(
        @RequestParam(name = "from")  String from,
        @RequestParam(name = "to")  String to,
        @RequestParam(name = "cil", required = false) List<String> cils,
        @RequestParam(name = "responsetype") ResponseType responseType,
        @NotNull @RequestHeader(value = "Oauth") String token
```

I tried to move all the parameters to a class, but since is a `GET` request it doesn't solve the issue with the URI characters limit.
I have the patch to change from `@RequestParam` to a `@RequestBody` and use a `POST` or `PUT` request instead of get, but I will prefer to solve it maintaining the `GET` request.

I have started thinking of sending a compressed String and then uncompress it in the controller, but I'm not sure about how to do it.

Can anyone provide me a hint about how can I proceed to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3684747 well, I don't use POST method because good practices says to not use it if you only want to get information. But if there is no other way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `server.max-http-header-size` default setting from 8kB to whatever size you need, but i would recommend using `POST` instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27950790/3684747